# Null Pointer on reading the screen orientation from Gluon Charm Down

Tags: java, ios, javafx, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I wanted to ask, if someone ever also had a problem using the Gluon Charm Down plugin for screen orientation for IOS?

JFXMobile Plugin: `org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2`

Charm Version: `com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0`

```
downConfig {
        version = '3.1.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'orientation'
}
```

When I try to call it, like this:

```
Services.get(OrientationService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
    onOrientationChange(service.orientationProperty(), null, service.getOrientation().orElse(Orientation.VERTICAL));
    service.orientationProperty().addListener(this::onOrientationChange);
});
```

I get an exception on the console:

```
Exception in Preloader start method
2017-02-06 10:43:37.104693 MyApp[447:282589] Orientation is Unknown
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Preloader start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.ios.IOSOrientationService.getOrientation(IOSOrientationService.java)
    at my.app.Preloader.lambda$start$24(Preloader.java)
    at my.app.Preloader$$Lambda$3.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java)
    at my.app.Preloader.start(Preloader.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.ios.BasicLauncher.main(BasicLauncher.java)
```

Looking at the [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/1942aa27c6b60d890511667cf64c3f9d8a0e69b6/plugins/plugin-orientation/ios/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/ios/IOSOrientationService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), I assume there could be only one reason for the issue:

```
@Override
public final Optional<Orientation> getOrientation() {
    switch (orientationText) {
        case "Portrait":
        case "PortraitUpsideDown":  
            return Optional.of(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        case "LandscapeLeft":
        case "LandscapeRight":      
            return Optional.of(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        case "Unknown":             
        default:                  
            return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

My guess is, that `orientationText` is `null` and therefore it crashes.

The line `2017-02-06 10:43:37.104693 MyApp[447:282589] Orientation is Unknown` contributes to that, I guess.

Is this a bug? Is there some way to circumvent this? (E.g. is there some set-up needed on IOS, like the permission system on Android?)

Thanks in advance and regards,

Daniel

---

**#edit:** The `onOrientationChange` method is not very complicated:

```
private void onOrientationChange(ObservableValue<? extends Orientation> obs, Orientation o, Orientation n) {
    if (n == null || splashPane == null)
        return;
    splashPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(vertical, Orientation.VERTICAL == n);
    splashPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(horizontal, Orientation.HORIZONTAL == n);
}
```

So I guess it would be sufficient to update the code to sth. like this

```
Services.get(OrientationService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
```

service.orientationProperty().addListener(this::onOrientationChange);
    });

(it's working on Android, so I could alternatively check the platform and only do it on non-IOS or so)

Comment: Given that the log gives a not null orientation, I don't think `orientationText` is null. Can you modify your event handler? Don't use `onOrientationChange` for now. Just print out the orientation new value: `service.orientationProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("O: " + nv));` and see if it fails.

Comment: I updated my question (see bottom of it) with the content of the `onOrientationChange` - but yeah, I can try that. Will give you the result after lunch, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your NPE.

The error happens when you 'eagerly' call `service.getOrientation()`.

If you have a look at the [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/d4fbce1340e5550babbc82e568def0d1966fbd0d/plugins/plugin-orientation/ios/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/ios/IOSOrientationService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), `orientationText` is not initialized, and it is only when the service is initialized and the observer starts that the value is retrieved from the iOS native layer and set with `Platform::runLater`.

This means that it takes a short while to get an initial value for `orientationText`.

The quick solution to avoid the NPE is using a regular `ChangeListener<Observation>` instead of your `onOrientationChange` method:

```
private final ChangeListener<Orientation> onOrientationChange = 
    (ObservableValue<? extends Orientation> obs, Orientation ov, Orientation nv) -> {
    if (nv == null || splashPane == null)
        return;
    splashPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(vertical, Orientation.VERTICAL == nv);
    splashPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(horizontal, Orientation.HORIZONTAL == nv);
}

Services.get(OrientationService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
    service.orientationProperty().addListener(onOrientationChange);
});
```

Anyway, I'll file an issue to add an initial value to `orientationText`.

Comment: Sorry, that I forgot to answer yesterday. Anyway: Yes - I already did as you suggested in your comment and removed the explicit `#getOrientation` call and only relied on the listener. Thanks a lot! Again...

Comment: No problem, the issue is fixed now. It is available with a Charm Down snapshot or after the next release.